# Magento 2 SOAP API ERROR

Tags: magento2, soap, soap-api-v2, soap-api-v1

I am using SoapUi to send a product to save changes the price per website for example here I am using the default website but it isn't working:
the Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
 xmlns:def="http://magento2/soap/default?
 services=catalogProductRepositoryV1">
 <soap:Header/>
  <soap:Body>
  <def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
     <product>
     <sku>I00204_SI-00</sku>
     <price>25.99</price>
     </product>
  </def:catalogProductRepositoryV1SaveRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

the Response:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
     <env:Code>
        <env:Value>rpc:ProcedureNotPresent</env:Value>
     </env:Code>
     <env:Reason>
        <env:Text>Procedure not present</env:Text>
     </env:Reason>
  </env:Fault>
  </env:Body>
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you get an answer..?

Comment: @MahendraJella I've opened a ticket here:https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/14626

Comment: @JulianoVargas  have you got solution?